# Will Entity Framework fail when running on a high volumn IIS web site

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, iis, objectcontext

We have been trying to analyse this exception:

> Message: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
>   Stacktrace:    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache)    at System.Activator.CreateInstanceT    at
>   Z.Services.ObjectContextManagement.ScopedObjectContextManager`1.get_ObjectContext()
>   at Z.Services.DatabaseAccess.DatabaseAccess`2.Manage()    at
>   Z.Services.DatabaseAccess.DatabaseAccess`2.get_ObjectContext()

Basically we get an error when getting the ObjectContext.

From this question: [Entity Framework lazy loading doesn't work from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575990/entity-framework-lazy-loading-doesnt-work-from-other-thread) we see that EF is dependent upon staying on the same thread.

From this Jon Skeet's answer to this question: [Will a request in IIS run on a single thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643987/will-a-request-in-iis-run-on-a-single-thread) we see that IIS has thread agility.

When there is a lower traffic volumn we do not see this error, but when the load increases we see the error.

So the question: If EF is dependent upon staying on a single thread, and IIS does not keep the request on a single thread, can EF be used on an application that is deployed on IIS?

**Edit**

```
var frameworkAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ObjectContextManager<>));
var managerType = frameworkAssembly.GetType(managerTypeName + "`1", true, true);
managerType = managerType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TObjectContext));
ObjectContextManager = Activator.CreateInstance(managerType) as ObjectContextManager<TObjectContext>;
```

It appears that the error occurs on the last line of the above code. The error only occurs in production under heavy load.

**Edit 2**

The ObjectContextManager inherits from ObjectContext which is an EF class.

```
 public abstract class ObjectContextManager<T> where T : ObjectContext
```

Comment: Given that EF IS deployed on a lot of web sites without problems, you should probaly check what you are doing wrong. Can you show the offending code?

Comment: This isn't EF code. This is about Activator failing to create a type. Are you sure managerType isn't null? BTW what is ObjectContextManager? Why are you creating the class like this? Why not just pass the context type as a type parameter?

Comment: I don't understand what this "thread agility" means. Do I have to care? I'd expect that IIS has to manage such thread changes without requiring me to program any synchronization. Horror, if your problem is really caused by IIS infrastructure...

Comment: BTW: I've changed the second link to the question/Skeet answer you likely meant. (You had the same (the first) link twice.) Can you check if it's correct?

Comment: EF is not thread safe meaning you cannot use the same ObjectContext instance (or other common EF objects like ObjectStateManager etc.)in multiple threads. However if you create a separate ObjectContext instance for each thread than you should be fine. As someone noted before neither in your stack trace nor in your example you are using anything that belongs to EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've hit some issues with thread agility and IIS recently. IIS can shift the thread of a request as it goes through the pipeline. This doesn't mean you have to be more aware of concurrency; what is important is the way context data is attached to the thread.

In an ASP.NET environment, this storage is done via the `HttpContent.Current` variable, which holds details for the current request being handled on the current thread. It does this via the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.HostContext` variable.

Many solutions for keeping data per thread make use of the `ThreadStatic` attribute, however this fails in an ASP environment because of the thread switch. The thread static starts off valued, then appears to become `null` midway through the processing pipeline.

ASP.NET will keep track of the `HttpContext`, the `CurrentPrincipal`, and possibly the locale as well. `CallContext` data and data stored in `ThreadStatic` variables is not copied.

The answer, while irritating, is to change the strategy and use `HttpContext.Current.Items` instead of `CallContext` or thread statics.

In your case, check the strategy in use for EF, and see if the implementation is pluggable.

As Jon Skeet points out, more information is available on [Cup(Of T)](http://piers7.blogspot.com.au/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html), but use this more as a launchpad for your discovery rather than an end in itself.