# Querying entity framework in parallel breaks lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing

I'm trying to load a lot of records from the DB and I would like to run them in parallel to speed things up.

Below is some example code which breaks when it tries to access the Applicants property which is null. However in a non-parallel loop, Applicants property is either populated or is an empty list, but is never null. Lazy loading is definitely enabled.

```
var testList = new List<string>();

Context.Jobs
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
                .ForAll(
                    x => testList.Add(x.Applicants.Count().ToString())
                );
```

Can I do something like this? Is it related to the entity framework connection? Can I make it parallel friendly and pass an instance of it into the task or something? I'm just shooting out ideas but really I haven't a clue.

Edit:

Is this post related to mine? My issue sounds kind of similar. [Entity Framework lazy loading doesn't work from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575990/entity-framework-lazy-loading-doesnt-work-from-other-thread?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLINQ does not offer a way to parallelize LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities queries. So when you call `AsParallel` EF should first materialize the query.

Furthermore, it doesn't make any sence to parallelize the query that executes on database, cause database can do that itself.

But if you want to parallelize cliend-side stuff, below code may help:

```
Context.Jobs
.Select(x => x.Applicants.Count().ToString())
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
.ForAll(
           x => testList.Add(x)
       );
```

Note that you can access navigation properties only before the query is materialized. (in your case before `AsParallel()` call). So use `Select` to get all what you want.

```
Context.Jobs
.Select(x => new { Job = x, Applicants = x.Applicants })
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
.ForAll(
       x => testList.Add(x.Applicants.Count().ToString())
   );
```

You also can use [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method to include navigation properties into results of the query...

```
Context.Jobs
.Include("Applicants")
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
.ForAll(
       x => testList.Add(x.Applicants.Count().ToString())
   );
```

Comment: I'm not looking to make the actual DB query parallel. I'm happy just calling Parallel.ForEach(Context.Jobs.ToList()...

But my problem is when I try to go down a graph level from the Job to Applicants. The Applicants are null

Comment: @LivingOnACloud - the EF's DbContext is not thread safe/capable so any time you access a navigation property or a DbSet from a thread that did not create the context you'll get null/exception.