# EF Include doesn't work on a iterative query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, entity-framework-plus

I'm working with C# EF 7.0.2, Z.EntityFrameworkPlus and SQL Server. I have a database that could be grown a lot and I want to make it scalable; To do this, I figure out to work with "chunks" to avoid timeout issues.

I have 4 entities

1. Products
2. Attributes
3. ProductAttribute (n:m)
4. RequestedProducts (List of user's requests to process products)

I was trying to process the products joining the entities Products and RequestedProducts, querying them by chunks (I'm using Take to avoid use OrderBy function, cuz in the local test that increment a lot the query result time) including ProductAttribute and Attributes entities. Then, when the parallel process ends, I'm using BatchUpdate to change de "Finished" flag so that next query doesn't include processed products (I'd understood that IQueryable doesn't execute the query until is necesary)

The first run of the query it works fine, but the next iteration the entities result doesn't include the ProductAttribute entities

```
IQueryable<Product> products = this.context.Products
    .Join(
        this.context.RequestedProducts.Where(x=>!x.Finished),
        p => p.Id,
        pp => pp.ProductId,
        (p, pp) => p)
        .Include(x => x.Attributes)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Attribute)
        .Include(x => x.Classifications);

IQueryable<StepProduct> queryToRun = products
        .Take(productLimit);

while(queryToRun){
    queryToRun
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(maxDegree)
        .ForAll(product =>
        {
            //Here is the process products code
        }
    this.context.RequestedProducts
            .Where(g => queryToRun.Select(q => q.ProductId).Contains(g.Id))
            .Update(new RequestedProducts(){ Finished=true });
    queryToRun = products        
        .Take(productLimit);
}
```

I tried to asign the full IQueryable to the queryToRun var, then I tried put the Include sentences in queryToRun and not in products, but it doesn't work. The first time all of the products entities have Attributes, but the next chunk, Attributes ever was empty.

Comment: How many records are you actually processing?

Comment: Hi @Alex, currently my test database have Products 3500 records,  ProductAtributes 175000, RequestedAtributtes 5000. On my tests I used chunks of 1000 elements and Max degree=25.  The prd database have at least 150,000 products and 7,000,000 ProductAtrributes records.

Comment: You should use an `.OrderBy` with any `.Skip` / `.Take` method, database tables don't have any defined order.

Comment: It looks like you are essentially downloading half a database in parallel fashion.
Far from being performant, this type of code will kill any database. And it seems that it is not designed to work that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418042/querying-entity-framework-in-parallel-breaks-lazy-loading

Comment: Why do you have these Includes? You don't do anything with the included data.

Comment: Hi @JeremyLakeman I'm trying to avoid to use OrderBy function, cuz in some tests with many data the query result time increments a lot. That's why I use Bulk to update the flag on RequestedProducts table to have less records on the next time that the query run

Comment: Hi @GertArnold sorry, I use these includes in the process product function, I don't include the code cuz it's a large and the my problem it's with query

Comment: @Alex I'm using the AsParallel function cuz the "Process product function" have call an very slowly API. Could you explain me why do you say that I'm downloading half a database? Honestly I thought that "Take" reduce the load on the client side

Comment: "I have a database that could be grown a lot and I want to make it scalable" - I am guessing that you are designing your code for some imaginary worst case scenario. Why? Based on the information presented I assume you have an OLTP database where some users/clients make requests for products (purchases?), which get queued and then a job processes them at certain points in time. Why wait until thousands of orders are piled up to start the process? Why not process it as soon as the user places item in the queue or trigger a processing job every 2 minutes?

Comment: If an order by for  5,000 records is causing a problems you have much bigger problems elsewhere.

`Include` operators in EF produce very "ugly" SQL queries that return a lot more data than is necessary. The amount of processing that has to be done by EF to transform this data into object trees is also non trivial.