# Is entityframework thread safe for multi threading?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, entity-framework, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to send some asnyc requests to google.api and if I run this classic foreach it works fine without any problem but when I replace with parallel.foreach it will sometimes not jump inside if because of
 keyword.AdGroup will be nothing in the if clause. When I watch  keywords list before it goes inside the parallel.foreach, all have Adgroup and Campaign sub object lazyloaded. But later inside foreach it somehow loses the AdGroup as it becomes nothing.  Is this something to do with Entity Framework with mutli threading?

```
Dim myDB As New DBContext

  Dim keywords As List(Of Keyword) = myDB.Keyword.ToList()

    Parallel.ForEach(keywords, New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, Sub(keyword As Keyword)

                                                                                            If keyword IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
                                                                                                keyword.AdGroup IsNot Nothing AndAlso keyword.AdGroup.Campaign IsNot Nothing AndAlso keyword.AdGroup.Campaign.CustomerId.HasValue Then
                                                                                                updateStatus(keyword.AdGroup.Campaign.CustomerId, keyword.AdGroupId, keyword.KeywordId, UserStatus.PAUSED)
Else

                                                                                            End If
```

EDIT:
I found similar question here but I am not clear with the answer. Can somebody illustrates with an example?

[Entity Framework lazy loading doesn't work from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575990/entity-framework-lazy-loading-doesnt-work-from-other-thread)

Comment: `If Keyword.AdGroup IsNot Nothing` only tests if AdGroup is nothing, if `KeyWord` is nothing, you'll get the exception

Comment: sorry, I have just changed my code because I forgot to indicate that myDB is DbContext. So I get the data from the DB unsing EF. in this case, I cant be nothing and It is not nothing. As I said the same code will work if I just replace with Classic Foreach

Comment: @Plutonix please see my edit. I founded that AdGroup becomes nothing inside the parallel foreach loop